# SharedPreferences getStringSet method not available

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

Very strange issue - I'm using the latest version of Android Development. Here is my code:

```
public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

Set<String> savedCityFare = editor.getStringSet(whatever);
```

Funny part is none of the getter methods are available for editor. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: dude, all getter methods are in SharedPreferences class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html you'll see that the SharedPreferences.Editor class only has putX() methods defined. If you want to use the getters, you don't need an Editor but only a SharedPreferences object.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
Set<String> savedCityFare = preferences.getStringSet(whatever);
```

I would also suggest using PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences() to obtain a SharedPreferences object.

## **JUST AN EDIT**

To add value in SharedPreferences:
`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YOUR_CONTEXT).edit().putXXX(YOURKEY,YOURVALUE).commit();`//This will directly save value in your SharedPreferences.

When you want to fetch the value from your Preferences:
`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YOUR_CONTEXT).getXXX(YOUR_KEY);`//THIS WILL Returned you the stored value.

Default Preferences are used when you want to maintain a single instance of SharedPreferences throughout the app.

Comment: thanks, very helpful. Can you expand a bit on your answer on how I can use PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPRefereces()?

Comment: @zooter getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context) is a static method in the PreferenceManager class; it will return a SharedPreferences instance pointing to the default file; so use it rather than getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); you can checkout more at [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context))

Answer (score 2):

> Funny part is none of the getter methods are available for editor

The getter methods are on the `SharedPreferences`. Only the setter methods are on the `SharedPreferences.Editor`. Think of the `SharedPreferences.Editor` as being a builder-style class for creating and executing a "transaction" to update the shared preferences.